# Kotlin MockK Static Methods executed instead of mocked

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, mockk

I have a simple Kotlin MockK test to mock a static method in setup().  However, instead of mocking, the underlying static method is just called? How do you properly mock static methods in Kotlin?

```
class Test {
    @Before
    fun setup() {
        mockkStatic(StaticClass::class)
        // mockkStatic(StaticClass::testStaticMethod)
        // mockkObject(StaticClass)

        // This calls the static method instead of mocking???
        every { StaticClass.testStaticMethod() } returns Unit  
    }
```

...

```
class StaticClass {
    companion object {
        // JvmStatic
        fun testStaticMethod() {
            print("why is this running still??") <== ???
```

1. Tried using `coevery` as well.
2. Happens in `setup` or `test` methods.
3. I import `io.mockk:mockk`.
4. I only use `mockk` no junit or other testing frameworks.
5. In my production test, this behavior causes my tests to fail as the static method relies on system setup not available in tests.
6. Gradle JVM = 17.0.9 - I don't get access exceptions as MockK mentions [here](https://mockk.io/doc/md/jdk16-access-exceptions.html).
7. Tried following [this accepted Github answer](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/136#issuecomment-419760399) mentioning to use mockObject for companion objects.

Comment: Is there a reason you use JUnit4 instead of 5? `@Before` is the old way of doing things. JUnit5 requires `@BeforeEach` for less ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

The code in your example wouldn't run for me with `Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block` error. However, when setup like described [here](https://mockk.io/#object-mocks) it runs and `print` inside `testStaticMethod` doesn't happen. I'm using JUnit5 here instead of JUnit4, but I don't think it matters.

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class Test {
    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
        mockkObject(StaticClass)
        every { testStaticMethod() } just Runs
    }

    @AfterAll
    fun tearDown() {
        unmockkObject(StaticClass)
    }

    @Test
    fun mainTest() {
        testStaticMethod()
    }
}
```